# Form API multiplie file upload validation error

Tags: forms, files, 8

I have a simple form with a multiple file upload field. I am trying to validate the documents against extensions and file size. The validation seems to work, but now if I don't select any file (field is not required), the validation fails and I get an error:

> **Fatal error:** Call to a member function getError() on a non-object in /home/www/test/core/modules/file/file.module on line 726

Here is my validation function:

```
public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $validators = array(
    'file_validate_extensions' => array('pdf doc docx xls xlsx txt jpg jpeg png gif'),
    'file_validate_size' => array(7 * 1024 * 1024), // 7MB file size limit
  );

  /** @var File[] $documents */
  $documents = file_save_upload('documents_upload', $validators, 'public://');
  $error = false;
  if(null !== $documents) {

    foreach($documents as $i => $document) {
      if ($document === FALSE) {
        $error = true;
      }
    }

    if ($error === true) {
      $form_state->setErrorByName('documents_upload', 'Error: could not upload file.');
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: No code, no answer.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me today. After some research it's appear that Drupal8 have a bug with empty file form element when this one is multiple.

The `file_save_upload` function expects an array looks like this when element is empty :

```
 ['form_field_name' => NULL]
```

But actually for an empty multiple file form element the array is:

```
 ['form_field_name' => [0 => NULL]]
```

So the condition check for an empty value and fail. The code continue until it try to use getError() on a null value.

Here is a function to check if a file were uploaded or not. You can use it in the validateForm callback of your form class or in a hook.

```
function isFileUploaded($form_field_name) {
  $all_files = \Drupal::request()->files->get('files', array());

  return isset($all_files[$form_field_name]) &&
    !empty($all_files[$form_field_name]) &&
    NULL !== reset($all_files[$form_field_name]);
}
```

It's not very pretty but it'll work until they fix that bug.